# Prove that the set U = {z ∈ C : -1<Re(z)< 1, -1<Im(z)< 1} is an open set. Then, prove or disprove that U is a star domain

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, proof-writing

any help on how to answer this question. I've managed to prove each one separately, but how would you go about proving both at the same time. Also, how would you prove that its a star domain.

Comment: To prove that $U$ is an open set, select an arbitrary point $x$ inside $U$, and consider a small open square that has $x$ in its middle (at the crossing point of the diagonals). Prove that the square is wholly contained in $U$. To prove that $U$ is a star domain it suffices to prove it is convex. To do so, select two arbitrary points $x$ and $y$ inside $U$, and show that any point $z$ on the segment that connects them (i.e. any $z$ of the form $z = tx+(1-t)y$ for some $t \in (0,1)$) belongs to $U$.

Comment: What's the issue with proving both at the same time? There are no complications whatsoever. If you proved that it's foo, and you proved that it is bar, you proved that it is foo and bar.

Comment: Could you show me the proof for both at the same time? Currently i've proved that its open for the set -1<Re(z)<1 and just assumed it holds for the entire statement as its open for the set of all imaginary numbers